# Not listening on Bluetooth if it was off when GKSession was initialized

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, gamekit

iOS app, GameKit with Bluetooth.

I want my app to be discoverable to instances of the same app on other devices. So I construct a GKSession on app startup and make it `available`. There's no success/failure feedback on that.

The problem is that if Bluetooth is turned off when the app is started, the app is not discoverable even if you turn BT on later. Hard-stopping the app and restarting helps, but I don't want to burden my users with that.

Can I somehow get a notification when the state of the BT is changed? Or get a failure code when trying to listen on a turned-off BT?